# Persisting a route parameter without passing it in every instance

Tags: laravel, routes, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm building a multi-client platform where the first parameter will always be the client's slug e.g. example.com/abc/orders. I want to be able to easily persist the slug, ideally without having to define it in every route in a vue context e.g.

```
<Link :href="route('admin.dashboard')">
```

Stack: Laravel 10, Vue, & Inertia.

---

Currently the options seem to me:

- Create custom helper: client_route(same, params, as, Ziggy) and merge the param here.

I've done this with a simple override of Ziggy's router before and just including the relevant param. Is this potentially shooting myself in the foot and is there a better approach? If I can easily pass the current user-client relationship to the module when loading it that'd be preferable to pulling the URL segment.

```
import Router from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/Router';

export default {
    install(app) {
        app.config.globalProperties.client_route = function (name, params, absolute = true, config) {
            if (typeof params === 'undefined') {
                params = {};
            }

            let url = window.location.pathname;
            let segments = url.split('/');
            let slug = segments[1];
            params.client_slug = slug;

            const router = new Router(name, params, absolute, config);

            return name ? router.toString() : router;
        }
    }
}
```

- Default functionality, pass the slug in every route, this is theoretical, I haven't tested to know if this code works, i.e. if the relationship access would work:

```
<script setup>
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const page = usePage();
const client_slug = page.props.auth.user.client.slug;
</script>

<Link :href="route('some.route', {client_slug: client_slug , ..otherparams})"></Link>
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but you can also consider a different approach for a multi-tenant platform: using a unique sub-domain for every client, this will solve your problem [and maybe might be in general a better approach]

Comment: Thanks Shaya, I love the idea of subdomains in general, but my issue with this approach is it's a very clear way to make your client-base easily identifiable. It's incredibly easy to do a lookup and I'm not sure of a reliable way to avoid this exposure.